# How can I "Go Back" without using Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

I have a html form that I process with a aspx page. I want to be able to go back to my html form if the validation on the aspx page returns false (I cannot use javascript to validate the html form). I can't use Response.Redirect as I will lose the data initially entered on the html form.

The set-up is:

- form.html (set action attribute of form tag to processform.aspx)
- processform.aspx (get values from html form using Request.Form["myvalue"])

if values are invalid, go back to form.html, otherwise Response.Redirect("success.html")

Perhaps I am just going about this the wrong way. Could anyone suggest a better method?

Please note: I cannot use javascript on the form.html, however I can use javascript on the processform.aspx page - although I would prefer an alternative if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that form.html can't use any javascript on form.html - does that mean you can't use Javascript at all in this solution?

My answer would be to output a javascript snippet from your processform.aspx that simply calls `history.go(-1)`.

Example:

```
if(valid) 
{
    Response.Redirect("success.html", true);
} 
Response.Clear();
Response.Write("<html><body><script>history.go(-1);</script></body></html>");
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

If, however, you cannot use Javascript at all... the options are rather limited.

RFC 2616 defines HTTP 204 "No Content" - you could attempt to send that, but this is a success status, and behaviour from browsers might vary. Theoretically, however, the content should stay the same.  Users might be very confused, however, because there's no visible feedback.

If you could explain the reasoning behind these restrictions, perhaps we could produce a better solution.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, however I was hoping to not have to use javascript at all. I can't use javascript with the form.html, but I could use javascript within the processform.aspx page. I might wait a while, see if anyone else has any other ideas. This is my first question on this site and I nearly fell out of my chair with a great answer in less than 10 mins from posting!

Comment: Clarified my answer. Looks like you might be able to get away with sending HTTP 204.  See how that goes.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to rethink the whole way I'm going about this. I will post another question with the full description of what I am trying to achieve over the weekend. Thanks for your input. Cheers, Tim

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC, you will have to refill the model from the submitted values in Request.Form.

If you are doing the classic WebForms, you need to generate your form.html dynamically inserting the previously submitted values into it.

You could put your submitted values into session:

```
Session["UserName"] = Request.Form["UserName"]
```

Then you do redirect to your form.aspx:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= Session["UserName"]" />
```

This will however return the page as form.aspx. But it shouldn't be a real problem, it's just the name.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to have the form submit to itself - that is, `<form action="" method="POST">`. The form, if retrieved using GET, simply displays itself. If it is retrieved using POST, it validates the posted information and, if there are any problems, re-displays itself as for GET, but with the errors flagged (and with the user's input preserved). If there are no validation errors, it does whatever it does with the information, and then uses `Response.Redirect()` to send the user to whatever the next page after a successful submission may be.

Comment: I used this method before but it has som x-browser issues

Comment: @Boris: Really? I've been using this approach since 1997 (the days of Netscape Navigator 3) and never encountered any issues. What problems have you encountered?

Comment: My form must be plain html (it can't be an aspx page), therefore I can't process the form data using the same page (the validation must be done within the processform.aspx page). So the only solution so far is to process the form data on the processform.aspx page and then "go back" if there are any validation errors.

Comment: According to the HTML specs the action element has to be set to a URL, so an empty action is not valid. But as NickFitz states this works in all browsers.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action

Comment: You might be right. I don't really recall what the issue was. But I remember using it a while back and for some reason taking an other approach. Sorry for the confusion and this rather vague post. I should learn to think before I write ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [`Server.Transfer`](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641).  It will internally reroute the request to another page without a redirect.  Use this to transfer to the page containing the form HTML.

Answer (score 0):

How about posting the form to another target? E.g. form target="_blank"

In the new window, perform the form data processing and then manipulate the html form page depending on the result.

It's untidy, but might just work for you.

PS: Do note that form target attribute is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two files into one, and show posted values in the form. Eg. `<input type="text" name="lorem" value="<?=Request.Form["lorem"] ?? "default value" ?>">`

If you have the form in a "dumb" html-file, you will not be able to inform the user of any validation errors, thus if the user enters incorrect data  and submits the form they will get back to the form without any information whatsoever on what went wrong, and that's a no-no!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this so I can find it later.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var employee = RequestPermission();
  if (!employee.Authorized) {
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
  }
  if (!IsPostBack) {
    //Load the grid for the initial page
  }
}
```

This does not use JavaScript (unless the underlying `Request.UrlReferrer` is written in JavaScript).

NOTE: **RequestPermissions** is a tool our company uses to match up employee information using **HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name** with a list of employee access information on our central server.